# Firestore web client dont point on emulator - Throwing PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Trying to do some basic firestore req but i am getting  permission error despite local rules allow everything:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Turns out the web client is using both online store and rules (not the local emulated), event though i put the config this way:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:  ///,
  authDomain: "http://localhost:3000",
  databaseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
  projectId: ///,
  storageBucket: "http://localhost:8080",
  messagingSenderId: ///,
  appId: ///,
  measurementId: ///
};
```

How am i supposed to configure the web client to make it point on the local emulated firestore?

Answer (score 0):

Find out that [this tutorial](https://google.dev/codelabs/firebase-emulator-get-started#2) is configuring the firestore web client this way:

```
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

  if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    console.log("localhost detected!");
    db.settings({
      host: "localhost:8080",
      ssl: false
    });
  }
```

My web client is now pointing on the local firestore.
(Can't find the reference in documentation though.)